# inserting html multiple times into php

Tags: php, html

I've got a html file ([thumbs up/thumbs down test page](http://stateofdebate.html)) that executes two php files...one for the thumbs up, and one for the thumbs down.

What I need to do now is insert this code into the page ([State of Debate debate list](http://stateofdebate.com)) so that each debate title can be ranked and move up and down accordingly.

My friend, who I have been working with, has done most of the coding, both PHP and tables.

My question is this: is there a way to get the thumbs up, thumbs down next to each debate title on the page? The best  I have gotten so far is getting all of the thumbs up/down above the table.

```
//test.html
<html>
<body>



<a href="upvote.php" onClick="alert('You have given this item a thumbs up! You can change          
your vote, or leave it how it is.')"; onMouseOver="return changImage()" onMouseOut=  
"return changImageBack()" ><img
name="jsbutton2" src="Graphics/thumbs-up-unclicked.jpeg" width="75" height="75" border="0"
alt="javascript button"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changImage()
{
document.images["jsbutton2"].src= "Graphics/thumbs-up.jpeg";
return true;
}
function changImageBack()
{
 document.images["jsbutton2"].src = "Graphics/thumbs-up-unclicked.jpeg";
 return true;
}
</script>


<a href="downvote.php" onClick="alert('You have given this item a thumbs down! You can change your vote, or leave it how it is.')"; onMouseOver="return changeImage()" onMouseOut= "return changeImageBack()" ><img
name="jsbutton1" src="Graphics/thumbs-down-unclicked.jpeg" width="75" height="75" border="0"
alt="javascript button"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changeImage()
{
document.images["jsbutton1"].src= "Graphics/thumbs-down.jpeg";
return true;
}
function changeImageBack()
{
 document.images["jsbutton1"].src = "Graphics/thumbs-down-unclicked.jpeg";
 return true;
}
</script>


</body>
    </html>

//upvote.php
<?php

session_start();

?>
<?php
$server = "X"; 
$dbusername = "X"; //database username 
$dbpassword = "X"; //database password 
$dbdatabase = "X"; //database name
$sqlconnect = mysql_connect($server, $dbusername, $dbpassword) or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $server");
$sqldb = mysql_select_db($dbdatabase,$sqlconnect) or die("Couldn't open database $dbdatabase"); 


$sql="INSERT INTO Votes (UID, date, rating)
VALUES
('{$_SESSION['UID']}', CURDATE(), 1)";


if (!mysql_query($sql,$sqlconnect))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_close($sqlconnect);
?>
```

Comment: If you give us your php code I can give you a much more precise solution. Otherwise I can just tell you how I'd have done it.

Comment: Alright. There's the html and php file (the downvote.php is essentially the same). I couldn't figure out how to not make them run together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When retrieving data from the database, as you cycle through each DB record, write one row of the table and while you're doing that, display an thumbs image as you cycle through. For example:

```
echo "<table>";

while { // loops through DB record matches...

    echo "<tr><td>" . $topic_name;

    if ($thumbs == 'UP') {
        echo "<img src='thumbsup.jpg'>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<img src='thumbsdown.jpg'>";
    }

    // Also, if you want clickable thumb up/down buttons, put them here 
    // and pass hidden form variables with the topic's unique record ID
    // & specific voting action to a submission page. 
    //
    // Sorta like this:
    // <form>
    // <input type='hidden' name='topicid' value='" . $id . ">
    // <input type='hidden' name='action' value='THUMBSUP'>
    // <input type='submit' value='THUMBS UP'>
    // </form>
    // & then repeat for thumbs down, only changing the 'action' field

    echo "</td><tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
```

Sorta make sense???

Comment: Yes, thanks, that makes a little sense (I'm a newbie web dev person). However, you may have misunderstood...the setup is to have the user be able to click EITHER thumbs up or thumbs down, which then writes into one of mySQL tables.

Comment: Added that form button stuff into the code. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Looks good. I just have some more figuring to do, looks like.

Comment: Also, you can make those thumb up/down buttons act as the form submit buttons, respectively. The code I typed would have the Thumb Up/Down graphic and then the voting buttons to the right of it (technically, beneath it, since I think <form> causes a line break).

Comment: Okay. The thing is, the graphics are the buttons.

Comment: No problem - just do this instead of the <input type='submit'...> stuff: <input type='image' src='thumbsup.jpg'> (Repeat for Thumbs Down also)